# XQUERY order by attribute

Tags: xml, attributes, sql-order-by, xquery

I want to order the following bit by the attribute length:

```
<border length="476" country="Serbia"/>
<border length="443" country="Ungaria"/>
<border length="531" country="Ucraina"/>
<border length="608" country="Bulgaria"/>
<border length="450" country="Republica Moldova"/>
```

I tried with the following code:

```
<mondial:ul> {
for $x in doc("romania.xml")/mondial/country
order by $x/border/@lenght
return <mondial:li>{data($x/border/@country)}</mondial:li>
}
</mondial:ul>
```

But it doesn't order anything. How can I do it?

Comment: If you show us a path selecting `doc("romania.xml")/mondial/country` with a sample not containing any `mondial` or `country` element we can't tell. Other than that, your spellchecker is broken and should have corrected `@lenght` as `@length`.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are trying to sort `<border>`s, not `<country>`s, so it should be

```
<mondial:ul> {
  for $x in doc("romania.xml")/mondial/country/border
  order by $x/@length
  return <mondial:li>{data($x/@country)}</mondial:li>
}
</mondial:ul>
```